# Can't run Laravel Artisan command from route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.6

I have an executable shell file and can successfully run it from CLI command but I'm having some issues running this artisan command from a route.

When I run it from the terminal I get the expected output message and the file gets copied, but running it from the route neither show anything in the log nor copy the file "cp .env .env.test".

I'm using laravel 5.6 and trying this on local env on Mac.

This is the shell file (shell.sh):

```
#!/bin/sh

php artisan cache:clear

cp .env .env.test
```

This is the Artisan Command

```php
    protected $signature = 'shell:run';


    protected $description = 'Run sheel file';


    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }


    public function handle()
    {
        $output = shell_exec('./shell.sh');

        $this->info($output);
    }
```

And the route:

```php
    Route::get('/shell', function () {
        Artisan::call('shell:run');
    });
```

Comment: What exit code are you getting from `call`? Any error message or exception is thrown? Could you consider replacing `shell_exec` with `Symfony\Component\Process\Process`?

Comment: Try with `Log::info($output);` instead `$this->info($output);`. Then look into `storage/logs/laravel.log` if is there the output

Comment: Instead of `Log::info`, you can catch output with by passing third argument (`call(string $command, array $parameters = [], $outputBuffer = null)`.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ: I tried to log the `$output` but it is blank `local.INFO:`.

Comment: @Haru I also tried your way and it returns 0 in the browser and I can't see file copied as per the shell code, means it didn't run.

Comment: Can we see that `shell.sh` script?

Comment: It's posted in the question already at the top.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that. What permissions does `shell.sh` script have? Is it executable and can be run by `www-data`?

Comment: @Haru Can you pls explain how to check/give this user permissions? Currently I can execute the shell file in Mac terminal using myself as a logged in user on the computer.

Comment: You can check that with `ls -l` (please send us what you get - single line with that script). Next, you might need to add an executable flag (`chmod +x script.sh`) and change the owner (`chown www-data:www-data script.sh`).

Comment: @Haru this is the output as requested `-rwxr-xr-x@  1 sohal  staff      52 27 Jun 23:57 shell.sh` and running `chown www-data:www-data script.sh` returns `chown: www-data: illegal group name`

Comment: It would be way easier to say if I know mac. Sadly, I don't. Apparently, mac is using a different user (perhaps, it's `_www`?). Tell me please what server are you using? Is it apache? Could you temporarily change permissions to 777 on this file (`chmod 0777 shell.sh` *it's insecure, don't use on production*)?

Comment: @Haru don't worry my friend, I'm already tired of researching different solutions on the internet and tired now. I'll find another solution to achieve what I want (probably use terminal instead of route/controller). Thanks for your help.

Comment: Alright then. I'm happy you've found working solution. I'll appreciate to see what happens if you put `0777` permissions to this file anyway. Could you do this for me?

Comment: @Haru I tried after changing the permissions to 0777 but no luck, nothing in the browser and log is empty too.